# Identifying feature columns with infinity values and handle it in pandas, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, imblearn

There are tons of questions and answers on this topic but I am not able to solve my issue.

I am trying to use the ADASYN model from imblearn to balance my dataset.

Here is my code so far:

```py
    df = pd.read_csv("data/"+filename, nrows=1000)
    df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
    df_imputed = df.fillna(df.mean())
    X = df_imputed.drop(['target'], axis=1)
    y = df_imputed.target
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
    from imblearn.over_sampling import ADASYN
    ada = ADASYN()
    X_resampled, y_resampled = ada.fit_sample(X, y)
```

But I get an error:

```
    ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

on the line

```py
    X_resampled, y_resampled = ada.fit_sample(X, y)
```

A couple of questions here:

1. How do you troubleshoot this issue? Meaning how do you identify the data causing this issue. My dataset has almost 2300+ feature columns.
2. How do you solve it?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Thanks Ben, tried swapping the lines and still get the same error.

Comment: Thank you Ben, that did it. Can you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problem to use `fillna` with `df.mean()` is that if the column contains only `nan` (or `inf` before as you `replace` by `nan`), then the column is still full of `nan` after the `fillna`. One way is to remove the columns that have only `nan`, because anyway these columns won't be useful for the ML model. To do so, you can use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and chain all the methods.

```
df_imputed = (df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
                .fillna(df.mean())
                .dropna(axis=1, how='all'))
```

Comment: Thank you, Ben. This was enlightening.